# Why comparison between two `*bytes.Buffer` type variables showing they are not equal even though they are same?

Tags: go

Here is the code for the problem. comparing the two buffer types shows they are not equal but two *File types are equal.

```golang
func main() {
    var v, w io.Writer
    v := &bytes.Buffer{}
    w := &bytes.Buffer{}
    v.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    fmt.Println(v == w) // false

    v := os.Stdout
    w := os.Stdout
    v.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    fmt.Println(v == w) // true

}
```

Comment: Because you are comparing the variables' addresses, not the contents of those variables. Also, event if you were comparing the non-pointer values, the `bytes.Buffer` type probably contains a `[]byte` which is a slice type and slices aren't comparable with plain `==`. For example `[]byte("hi") == []byte("hi")` is illegal. Read more [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators).

Comment: You want to compare the content (e.g. string) written into the buffers, so call their `String()` method to obtain the written `string` and compare those, e.g. `v.String() == w.String()`.

Comment: `v := &bytes.Buffer{}; w := &bytes.Buffer{}` creates two different pointers. obviously they will never be equal since it is two separate objects.

Comment: You can compare the byte slices using [`bytes.Equal`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Equal). Comparing two pointers to different objects will never be equal; if it did, that would be a critical flaw in the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing **pointers**, not objects. The expression `&bytes.Buffer{}` creates a new object in memory and returns a pointer to it. Doing that twice would give two different pointers, since no two objects can reside at the same memory location.

To compare the actual **contents** of buffers, use something like `bytes.Compare(v.Bytes(), w.Bytes())`

```
    v := &bytes.Buffer{}
    w := &bytes.Buffer{}
    v.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    fmt.Printf("%p, %p\n", v, w)                     // prints 2 different values
    fmt.Println(bytes.Compare(v.Bytes(), w.Bytes())) // 0, means "equal"
```

Regarding the second case, `os.Stdout` is a global variable containing a pointer to `os.File`, so the snippet compares two pointers to the same object.

```
    v := os.Stdout
    w := os.Stdout
    v.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    w.Write([]byte("Blah!")) // doesn't matter
    fmt.Println(v == w) // true: v and w point to the same object!
```